# storing data from multiple select form to MYSQL using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am looking for help on storing data from multiple select form to MYSQL using PHP, here is my form

```
            <form action="" method="post">

            Choose your preferred browser
            <select name="browsers"> 
            <option value="Internet Explorer">
            <option value="Firefox">
            <option value="Chrome">
            <option value="Opera">
            <option value="Safari">
            </select>

            Choose your preferred car
            <select name="carlist">
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="opel">Opel</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
            </select>

            <input type="submit">
            </form>
```

Comment: Are you asking about how to actually store the data in the DB? I mean DB architecture? OR are you asking about how to do it in PHP? If latter is the case, then add your DB structure for this data, please.

Comment: Yes, storing to Mysql database..

Comment: There are multiple options. If you don't need to search by preferred car, you can save it in one column in a json.  Other option is to use N:M relation, where each user can have multiple preferred cars.  If there is finite and small number of columns, like for the browsers, you can also use a separate column for each one with a bool value in it.
Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_POST['browser'];` and `$_POST['carlist'];` each hold their own different value. So you can easily fetch each of their values.

```
$car = $_POST['carlist'];
$browser = $_POST['browser'];
```

Now it's just a matter of question where you wanna take it from there. F.ex. if you'd like to save it to a database;

```
// Just make it a standard to secure your database inputs
$car = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['carlist']);
$browser = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['browser']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO someTable (car, browser) VALUES ('".$car."', '".$browser."')";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

This is very simplified of course, but I hope it gives you an idea.